# ZF2 Forms Standalone - How can I get access to my custom view helpers?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

We are using the ZF2 forms as a standalone plugin inside another PHP application. This is working fine, except I'm not able to use some custom view helpers. The `ServiceManager` (?) doesn't know where my helpers are located and crashes with a fatal error.

Is there a way to register some custom view helpers without a `modules.config.php`? I haven't found a way to pass an array/config to the `HelperConfig` below. As a ZF2 rookie I'm a bit lost here.

```
$form = new \My\Custom\Form\ContactForm();
$renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$config = new \Zend\Form\View\HelperConfig();
$config->configureServiceManager($renderer->getHelperPluginManager());

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $form->setData($_POST);

    if($form->isValid()) {
        $data = (OBJECT) $form->getData();
        // ...
    } else {
        return $form->render($renderer); // Inside the render() method we use the form-view-helpers to render the form.
    }
} else {
    return $form->render($renderer);
}
```

I have also tried to use the `HelperPluginManager` (Btw. whats the difference between these two?). But there isn't a method to pass a config-array either.

```
$renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$plugins = $renderer->getHelperPluginManager();
$renderer->setHelperPluginManager($plugins);
```

Comment: Did you try to register your custom helpers by using: `HelperPluginManager::setService($name, $service)` or any of the other methods like `setFactory($name, $factory, $shared = null)`? Instead of trying to pass a config/array to the `HelperPluginManager`.